# WordPress Theme backend admin panel section feature image doesn't appear?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress theme name Perth Pro. I have edited this to create home page. But when I edit the employee section in the back end admin panel following properties doesn't appears i.e 
- Featured Image
- Categories
and some other feature for edit the employee section. Can i get help?

Comment: if you edit page!!! then there is no featured image and categories displayed because those features are only for  POST

Comment: Share some screenshots

Comment: but in this theme when edit the post all the feature of admin panel is working properly . But when edit the employee section which is same as the post section the categories and feature image section not appear in admin panel (employee section is working as same work post in this theme)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the **employee** is post type, which does not allow **thumbnail image**[ i.e Featured Image ].
You may need to change the code where the Post Type is defined :
Just check and add the following :

```
'supports'              => array( 'title','thumbnail','editor')
```

May in your code 'thumbnail' is missing, please add that.